# How to use a Subclassed Control on an ASP.NET Page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, subclass

I've subclassed `DropDownList` to add functionality specific to my application:

```
public class MyDropDownList : DropDownList
{
    ...
}
```

... then referenced it in `Web.Config`, which is where I figure things start to go wrong:

```
<pages theme="Main">
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="bob" tagName="MyDropDownList" src="~/Components/MyDropDownList.cs" />
    </controls>
</pages>
```

my reference to it does not work:

```
<tr><td>Category</td>
   <td><bob:MyDropDownList runat="server" ID="Category"... />
```

and my best clue is the complier error message:

```
"The file 'src' is not a valid [sic] here because it doesn't expose a type."
```

I figure I'm misapplying knowledge of how to create a Web User Control here. What I want to be able to do is refer to this control on an ASP.NET page just like I would the parent `DropDownList`. Refactoring back into a Web User Control that contains a `DropDownList` is not desirable, because I want to apply a `RequiredFieldValidator` to it.

Comment: You added only cs file with your MyDropDownList control? I thought that when you create new control you always add both .ascx and .cs files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
<pages theme="Main">
    <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="bob" namespace="MyProject" assembly="MyProject" />
    </controls>
</pages>
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Based on what I've been reading so far, this sounds better than what I'm doing. It doesn't work, tho', and I think it's because the containing project is a "Web Site" rather than a "Web Application". I'm going to create a sub-project, drop it in there, make the appropriate reference in Web.Config then report back.

Answer (score 5):

@Joops answer saved me.

What I did differently was to register the namespace at the top of my page because I didn't need it everywhere.

ie.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="myTagPrefix" Namespace="MySolution.MyProject.Foo.Bar"
        Assembly="MySolution.MyProject" %>
```

cheers Joop!