# Custom web control without a DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, custom-controls, ascx

I am trying to inherit a dropdownlist. I don't want to compile it and put into a DLL. I want to reference it from the same project, and that component will be used by two other pages, only.

The code-behind is very basic:

**.cs page:**

```
namespace UNS
{
    public partial class UDropDown : DropDownList
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

**.ascx page**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UDropDownList.ascx.cs" Inherits="UNS.UDropDown" %>
```

I want to give reference to this in another .aspx page by registering it like:

**.aspx page**

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UDropDownList.ascx" TagPrefix="UTP" TagName="UTN" %>
```

The question is, when I want to put it on the page, if I write

```
<UTP: ...
```

I cannot get auto complete options, etc. It doesn't appear.

But I can refer to it within other **.cs** pages, by simply typing UDropDown.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solved the problem:

[How to use a Subclassed Control on an ASP.NET Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432856/how-to-use-a-subclassed-control-on-an-asp-net-page)

I used web-config to register my control.

**web.config**

```
<pages theme="UTheme">
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="UTP" namespace="UNS" assembly="UNS" />
  </controls>
</pages>
```

Created a new class, not a partial class:

**UDropDownList**

```
namespace UNS
{
    public class UDropDownList : DropDownList
    {
    }
}
```

On the **.aspx page**, do refer to it like:

```
<UTP:UDropDownList runat="server" ID="dd" runat="server"
                ClientIDMode="Static" AutoPostBack="false">
</UTP:UDropDownList>
```