# error inheriting web control

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to add a new custom web control to my asp.net application.

Here is the code for my custom control

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MyPersonalCareHealthRecord.classes.extended
{
    public class TableHeaderDataCell : TableHeaderCell
    {
        public string MappedDataField { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my markup I am using the following code

```
    <dt:TableHeaderDataCell CssClass="HeaderField" runat="server">Test1</dt:TableHeaderDataCell>
```

After getting some errors, doing some research, and reading this article
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/1e9b4c9f(v=vs.80).aspx (along with referencing a book I have on asp.net) I tried adding in a register directive like this one and adjusted my markup to the above.

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dt" TagName="TableHeaderDataCell" namespace="MyPersonalCareHealthRecord.classes.extended" %>
```

However on trying to load the page I get an error: "The directive is missing a 'src' attribute."
I tried changing my directive to:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dt" TagName="TableHeaderDataCell" src="~/Classes/TableHeaderDataCell.cs" %>
```

and then got error: "The file 'src' is not a valid here because it doesn't expose a type."
After further research and finding this stackoverflow article [How to use a Subclassed Control on an ASP.NET Page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432856/how-to-use-a-subclassed-control-on-an-asp-net-page)
I tried changing my register directive to

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dt" TagName="TableHeaderDataCell" namespace="MyPersonalCareHealthRecord" assembly="MyPersonalCareHealthRecord" %>
```

which resulted in error: "The directive is missing a 'src' attribute."
Adding the src attribute in gave me error: "The 'namespace' attribute is not supported on this directive when a 'tagname' attribute is present."

Removing the tagname attribute gave me errors and removing the namespace tagname did as well....

I realize this was a lengthy question but can anyone help me??? I don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: It looks like your trying to point the source to a class file, a custom user control should be ascx. I think, did you actually go to  add new file, then click webforms user control or did you add class?

Comment: @prospector I simply added the class... I will try the .ascx file and see what happens, (forgive me, I'm new to asp.net) but what would I put in the ascx file since the only change I am making is adding a member to the source code???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I believe I have solved it.... I followed the instructions at this link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa310915(v=vs.71).aspx

I created a .dll from my custom control source code file and then made sure the .dll was in the /bin directory in my project. changed my register directive to be:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dt" Namespace="MyPersonalCareHealthRecord.classes.extended" Assembly = "TableHeaderDataCell" %>
```

(TableHeaderDataCell is the name of the dll file)
At first I got an error about the type being in two places so I had remove the .cs file from the bin directory before it would work. I also had some issues referencing my new type in the actual code behind file so I had to add a reference and browse to the new dll and add a reference to it in my project. After adding the reference I was able to use it in my code behind file.

Answer (score 1):

Go to add a Webforms User Control.

Once you add it go to code behind of the control (the cs file) and you can put your property there

```
public string MappedDataField { get; set; }
```

Save it.

Go to solution explorer and simply drag it in your web form.

In your webform code behind you can access that property.

```
MyControlName.MappedDataField = "whatever text";
```

Comment: I actually fixed this before I saw this post (see my answer). I will probably try going this route as well and see which one is easier/works better. After trying it I will select an answer. Thanks for the help here.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't work. I am actually trying to extend a "Web" control not a "User" control... I tried using what you suggested but got some errors. This would probably work fine if I was trying to extend a user control.